# Taking an upstream story branch and merging it to multiple 'parent' branches

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

So our scenario is this:

- dev_mvp
- dev_mvp_features
- dev_wave1_features
  --+ story_branch_1
  --+ bugfix_branch_1

What we're being asked to do is to have the code that we are working on in those story/bugfix branches and merge it (and only it) into the 3 root branches, not just the 1 parent branch.

So we open a PR (Azure Dev Ops) to merge the code from, say, story_branch_1 to dev_wave1_features. We review and approve that PR, that code is merged.

The dev ops team is asking us to then CHERRY PICK that commit into dev_mvp_features and dev_mvp. Cherry Pick is not the right solution here, especially with over 20 people doing code changes across multiple streams of work and attempting to get that code into those root branches.

Can't we just do the PR, then checkout dev_mvp_features and do a `git checkout dev_mvp_features && git merge story_branch_1` ? Then repeat for dev_mvp?

Comment: Of course you *can*. The question is not *can* you, but rather *should* you. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180323-01/?p=98325 (check out the last blog entry as well as the first ten).

Comment: Oh yes, I read through that article a week ago or so, which enlightened me to the fact that we shouldn't be cherry picking. That's my concern. Does that series explain how to do what I'm trying to do? I need to go back and read it again if so.

Comment: Basically, it's a recipe (with good theoretical grounding, though I forget if he describes the theory part) for how to fix bugs in a way that *does* allow merging, such that future merges are also simplified. To oversimplify it, you fix the bug in a fixing-the-bug commit that is as close, historically speaking, as possible to the bug origin: preferably a new branch just for the purpose of fixing the bug immediately after it's first introduced. That branch can then easily merge into all current branch-tips that are descendants of the bug.

Comment: ah well we're well away from that unfortunately. They're just hitting these defects well after they're introduced. The problem we're seeing is we just end up having to do tons of merge conflict handling. It sucks.